# Opencv floodfill fails on corners

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a strange behaviour using opencv floodfill, I've a set of brush annotations that contains small holes here and there and I'm trying to fill these holes. I'm using this code

```
im_floodfill = anno.copy()
cv2.floodFill(im_floodfill, None, (0, 0), 255)
floodfill_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(im_floodfill)
anno = anno | floodfill_inv
```

which works perfectly on the majority of images, but I've found two images on which this code fails, both of them have an annotation around a corner like in the image
[image: annotation]

Which results in floodfill_inv being
[image: inverse floodfill]

And I really don't understand what it's going on, it fills the small holes in the image properly but it also fill the rest of the image, at most I would expect to fill out the top left corner (which would still be a problem in my case).

Anyone has an idea on why is working like this?

I'll add an example of a correct result
[image: annotation n2]

[image: floodfill inverse correct]

Using the suggestion from the comments I wrote the code to draw contours and use centroid as seed point for the floodfill algorithm

```
        anno = cv2.imread(anno_path, 0)
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(anno, mode=cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        img_contours = np.zeros(anno.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
        cv2.drawContours(img_contours, contours, -1, 255, 3)

        im_floodfill = img_contours.copy()
        for i in contours:
            moment = cv2.moments(i)
            x_center = int(moment["m10"] / moment["m00"])
            y_center = int(moment["m01"] / moment["m00"])
            cv2.floodFill(im_floodfill, None, (x_center, y_center), 255)

        anno = anno | im_floodfill
```

Initially it seemd to work, but on a different image I found another failure, the centroid point is not guaranteed to lie inside my annotation area (for example in a U shaped annotation), if it's outside the floodfill will just fill the whole image again!

Comment: The `(0, 0)` in the function `cv2.floodFill` is called the seed point. The floodfill operation begins at that point, which is the **top-left** corner of the image. What is your expected output?

Comment: I would expect the inverse floodfill to be white only on the holes of the input annotation as it happens for basically all the other images, so that the or with the input results in an image with the holes filled.
In this case instead all my image except the left corner gets filled with white and the resulting output is for this reason, wrong.

Comment: I've added what I would expect to get taken from a different annotation.

Comment: You can find contours in the image and the centroid of each contour. Assign the centroid as the seed point within `floodFill` iteratively.

Comment: It could be right solution, I'll give it a shot as soon as I can, meanwhile I tried setting to zero 1px around all the image and it fix the issue but is more of a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: You need to set up a mask image for cv2.floodfill. See the docs at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gaf1f55a048f8a45bc3383586e80b1f0d0

Comment: !scorpion2k40. Can you post original image, please?

Comment: @JeruLuke I've found an issue on your idea, or maybe I'm still missing a piece, I've updated the question.

Comment: @toyotaSupra These are the original images attached to the question https://wetransfer.com/downloads/203d647e6d6e6867a86d720f4577bc4d20220711130556/64279d

Comment: “why is working like this?” Because you flood full from the top-left corner, not from all the edges. You need to start the flood fill at all edge pixels. No idea how to do so in OpenCV.

Comment: If you’re looking for an alternative, all I can do is suggest [DIPlib](https://diplib.org/) (I’m an author). The [FillHoles](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/binary.html#dip-FillHoles-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-uint-) function does what you need.